# Gradle Incremental Builds - possible to ignore manifest in up-to-date check?

Tags: java, jar, gradle, build.gradle

The subject pretty much asks the question, but for more detail, I have the following in my `build.gradle`:

```
jar {
    manifest {
        attributes("Built-By": "Gradle")
        attributes("Build-Version": version)
        attributes("Main-Class": "somePackage.SomeClass")
    }
}
```

When building, since the manifest is auto-generated, it always thinks the `jar` task is out of date, even if nothing has changed in the code.

**Ideally**, I'd like to be able to check to see if the version is the same as the last build.  If it is, and if previous task dependencies (`compileJava` et al) are all `UP-TO-DATE`, I'd like the jar task to report `UP-TO-DATE` as well.

Failing that, I'd be pretty happy if I could just get the jar task to ignore the manifest file altogether.

For an individual jar task this isn't such a big deal, but as soon as one jar reports that it's not `UP-TO-DATE`, all the tasks that depend on it then have to re-compile, re-jar, etc etc, which makes builds take way longer than they actually need to.  And since the very first jar task in my dependency path reports that it's not up-to-date because of the manifest issue, that means the whole thing is forced to recompile/re-jar/re-war/re-ear/etc every-single-time, and we're talking about a few hundred thousand lines of code here.

Anyway, if anybody knows of a way to solve this little annoyance I'd be grateful

**EDIT**

I also have a zip task that depends on the jar task:

```
task zip(type:Zip, dependsOn:jar) {
    from jar
    include jar.archiveName
    from '.'
    include 'run.bat'
}
```

Running this command:

```
gradlew :myProject:zip -Pversion=1.0
```

I consistently get the following output every time, even if I run it twice in a row with no changes anywhere:

```
:myProject:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:myProject:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:myProject:classes UP-TO-DATE
:myProject:jar
:myProject:zip
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given above declaration, and assuming that code hasn't changed, the `jar` task should only be out-of-date if `version` has changed. (Running with `--info` will tell you which file(s) have changed.) Best solution is to prevent that, at least at development time. (E.g. don't set `version` to `new Date()`.)

Also note that out-of-date does *not* cascade. Downstream tasks will only rerun if *their* inputs or outputs have changed. They don't care if upstream tasks were up-to-date or not.

Comment: Peter - I've been setting "version" on the command line via -Pversion=1.0 so it is empirically the same each time.  The reason I think out-of-date is cascading is that say task B depends on the output of task A, if task A comes up out-of-date, task B then recompiles, re-jars, etc.

Comment: This is something I've noticed on all of my builds, but in this particular case it's small enough to easily see the behavior.  I build my jar using the above code, then I have a zip task that depends on the jar task.  The code doesn't change, the version stays at 1.0.  See my edit so you can see what the behavior.  I get the same result each time

Comment: What I'm saying is that B will recompile iff A's output (e.g. Jar contents) has changed. It doesn't matter whether A was up-to-date or not. You can't set predefined model properties like `project.version` from the command line, without special arrangements in the build script. `-P` always creates a *new* property. (Practically speaking, `-P` isn't much different from `-D`.) In the case of `-Pversion`, you'll end up with a new property that's shadowed by `project.version`.

Comment: You can figure out what changes between builds by running with `--info`, noting down the changed files, and comparing them against previous copies.

Comment: Ok, so the problem is that the build-date attribute is being added from the `subprojects` block of the root project, even though (I thought) I was overriding that by putting the above manifest block in my subproject.  Is there a way to completely override the manifest block specified in the subprojects block of the root project?

Comment: Or, back to my original question, ignore the manifest unless the version (not the build date) changes?

Comment: In general, it's always better to target a piece of configuration at the right places from the beginning. (You can target any subset of projects, not just `subprojects`. Alternatively, you can add some conditional logic there. See [Gradle User Guide](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/userguide_single.html) for details.) Overriding later can be hard or impossible (perhaps try `attributes = [:]` in this case.) As is ignoring the manifest for up-to-date checks.